# Converting String return method to jSON via Rest

Tags: java, angularjs, json, spring-mvc

i have a spring method in my controller that has a String type return result when i consume The Web Service by Angular ($http) i get

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token a at Object.parse (native)
```

this is my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/loggeduser",method=RequestMethod.GET, produces =MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
public ResponseEntity<String> findMessagesForUser(Principal principal) {
    System.out.println("looged user login="+principal.getName());
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(principal.getName(), HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

and this my Angular Function :

```
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/projet/rest/users/api/loggeduser").success(function(data) {
     console.log(data);      
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The media type of the response is `MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` therefore Angular tries to parse the response data as JSON and this fails. Use `MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use it like this angular won't recognize what type of data you sending so try sending it with double quote to escape double quote use the antislash or you can change mediaType to text plain

```
String name=" \" "+principal.getName()+" \" ";
```